How do I prove the amount of a flight delay in UK court?
I'll likely be taking easyJet to court over a meal expense; they claim the flight in question was only delayed by 50 minutes, while in fact it was delayed by 2.5 hours on departure (the threshold being 2 hours for the relevant route).
FWIW it's this flight:
https://www.flightaware.com/live/flight/EZY8106/history/20240801/2305Z/LEIB/EGKK
https://www.flightera.net/en/flight_details/easyJet-Ibiza-London/U28106/LEIB/2024-08-02
What would a judge be likely to accept as proof that easyJet are mistaken about the delay? I've had one nonchalantly dismiss FlightAware in a different context, and the other options I'm familiar with are FlightRadar24 and Flightera as well as requesting an email confirmation from the departure airport.

Not sure how answerable this is, perhaps more appropriate on law.SE? I would guess it might depend on the country but law allows multiple responses for each country.

@Relaxed It'll be in UK court. Just posted in law.SE as well

Please do not cross post on different Stack Exchange sites. Certainly not the exact same question. Please close one or the other or edit so one is specific for Law and the other for Travel.

Assuming you’re bringing a civil case in a County Court, this page describing evidence needed to sue someone might be helpful

@Traveller Yes, it's a civil case on a County Court, but no, my question is far more specific than what that site covers

Not sure if it’s any likelier to be admitted than FlightAware or FlightRadar24, but the departures page on Ibiza Airport’s website uses data from Avionio, which lists your flight as departing 2:50 hours late. The most ironclad proof would probably be if you could get your hands on Ibiza Airport’s own data somehow.

@JanusBahsJacquet: You can subpoena the airport for its records. Since the airport is in a different country, the expense of doing so likely outweighs the value of the case. You can also subpoena the airline for their records, but if those records do not agree with reality then you will need to find some other source to prove that fact.

Note: the delay is about arrival at destination, not departure, still above 2h but you should prove that. And just affirm your estimate time of arrival. If complain to airline is not sufficient, you have the possibility to claim on the aviation authority which. I think. should be able to find exact times. (I think courts are in a further step, and yeah in such case you may need to prepare all proofs)

@GiacomoCatenazzi Absolutely not: for meal expenses the rights are triggered when the airline "reasonably expects" the departure to be delayed by at least 2 hours (if below 1500 km)

A receipt for the meal showing date and time would be quite conclusive.  You're showing a receipt to prove the amount of damages anyway, correct?
The fact that you were purchasing food at a ground establishment during the time they claim the plane was already on its way (or at least, boarding), and they agree that you made it onto the plane, will disprove their account of the timeline.
If you didn't eat during the delay, you may have some trouble claiming that the expense was caused by the delay.
In any case, get their claim that the departure was only 50 minutes late in writing and send it off to the regulator... the fine for falsifying flight records is likely to cost them many orders of magnitude more than your meal.

Rather than asking them for the delay time, it might be worth asking specifically for the actual time of departure in writing. That's something that should be simpler and more obvious for the regulator to check and also easy for you to demonstrate to the court if they present a narrative of delay time and departure time that is inconsistent with your flight tickets.

Presumably easyJet will have to prove its delay time assertion by providing the court with its official flight data. Punctuality statistics from the CAA might help the OP
